# Entry not updating tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Im trying to make a rock paper scissors game using the python module tkinter to create a window with an input box. However im struggling to get the entry box to update to another value everytime i press the button.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry('450x350')
root.configure(bg='yellow')


#Global variables
text = []
buttonClicked = False

def changeValue():
    global buttonClicked
    if buttonClicked:
        buttonClicked=False
    if not buttonClicked:
        buttonClicked=True

def button_command():
    global text
    text.append(player_entry.get())
    player_entry.delete(0, END)

def final_calculation():
    cmpt_choice = random.choice([0, 1, 2])

    def determine_win(user_choice, cmpt_choice):
        return (user_choice + -cmpt_choice) % 3
        
    if text[0] == 'Rock' or text[0] == 'rock':
        player_choice = 0

    elif text[0] == 'Paper' or text[0] == 'paper':
        player_choice = 1

    elif text[0] == 'Scissors' or text[0] == 'scissors':
        player_choice = 2
    
    else:
        player_choice = 3
        print('Something went wrong with the input')

    if player_choice != 3:

        print(determine_win(player_choice, cmpt_choice))
        return determine_win(player_choice, cmpt_choice)


#Player
player_label = Label(root, text='Rock / Paper / Scissors')
player_entry = Entry(root, width= 20)
player_button = Button(root, text="Confirm", command=lambda:[button_command(), changeValue(), final_calculation()])


player_entry.pack()
player_label.pack()
player_button.pack()

#Positioning
player_entry.place(x = 100, y = 175, anchor = 'center')
player_label.place(x = 100, y = 140, anchor = 'center')
player_button.place(x= 205 , y = 175, anchor = 'center')



root.mainloop()
```

What im struggling with i.e if I was to write `Rock` as an input (assume computer response is always 0):

Then my output would be `0` this is correct, however if my next input was something random like `dsadsad` the desired output would be `'Something went wrong with the input'`. However it seems like the first input is saved and is continusly used since the output would still be `0`.

If we on the other hand start with the input `dsdasdasd` the output would read: `'Something went wrong with the input'`. And if we then wrote the input as `rock` the output would still read `'Something went wrong with the input'` instead of the desired output `0`.

Any help appreciated,

OBS! this might not be the most efficient way of programming this form of programm but im new to programming.

Comment: Notice that you define `player_choice` inside the function only? That could be why. I dont understand how you would relate between `player_entry` and `player_choice`. Furthermore instead of using `or`, just use `lower()` method of string.

Comment: You use `text[0]` in comparison but you do not update `text[0]` with the new value but append to it inside `button_command()`.  So the new value will be `text[1]`, `text[2]`, etc.

Comment: In short, `text[0]` always remains constant, you have to play change `0` to `-1` maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statements are at fault. You are always comparing the user input with the first item on the list, with `text[0]`, you need to change that to `text[-1]` to get the last item appended to the list. So your function would be:

```
def final_calculation():
    global player_choice
    cmpt_choice = random.choice([0, 1, 2])

    def determine_win(user_choice, cmpt_choice):
        return (user_choice + -cmpt_choice) % 3
        
    if text[-1].lower() == 'rock':
        player_choice = 0

    elif text[-1].lower() == 'paper':
        player_choice = 1

    elif text[-1].lower() == 'scissors':
        player_choice = 2
    
    else:
        player_choice = 3
        print('Something went wrong with the input')

    if player_choice != 3:

        print(determine_win(player_choice, cmpt_choice))
        return determine_win(player_choice, cmpt_choice) # Button callbacks have no use returning data
```

You can also remove `or` and convert all text to lower or upper case and then compare between them. I am also assuming this is not the entire code, because some of your functions don't have any true purpose (yet?) and returning from a button callback is of no use too.